# How can I convert a md5 hash to an integral type in Java?

Tags: java, hash, integer, md5

I am trying to convert a md5 hash to a `long` like I can in python,

> ```
> >>> int(hashlib.md5("abc").hexdigest(),16) 
> 191415658344158766168031473277922803570L
> ```

When I digest "abc", I get (in Hex): "0X900150983CD24FB0D6963F7D28E17F72"

What is the correct way to do this hash conversion in Java?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] md5hex = DigestUtils.md5("abc");
    String hex = new String(Hex.encodeHex(md5hex));
    System.out.println(hex);
    long lv = Long.parseLong("0X" + hex.toUpperCase(), 16);
    System.out.println(lv);
    int hext = Integer.parseInt("12346789", 16);
    System.out.println(hext);
}
```

Comment: An MD5 is 16 bytes long. An `int` can hold 4 bytes, a long can hold 8 bytes. So there is no correct way to convert a md5 hash to a long or an int.

Comment: what Exception *and i got the exception* would that be then?

Comment: i can do it in python  : >>> int(hashlib.md5("abc").hexdigest(),16)
191415658344158766168031473277922803570L

Answer (score 6):

First, let's take a good hex encoder like the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338/2970947) from [maybeWeCouldStealAVan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284661/maybewecouldstealavan)

```
private final static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

Then use `MessageDigest` and [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) (an arbitrary precision integer type, which is what your python code is using)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        byte[] md5hex = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest("abc".getBytes());
        System.out.println(new BigInteger(bytesToHex(md5hex), 16));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and I get

```
191415658344158766168031473277922803570
```

**Also**, if you do

```
System.out.println(bytesToHex(md5hex));
```

I too get

```
900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
```

Comment: What's the point of `new BigInteger(xxx, 16).toString(16)`? It's the same as `xxx`, i.e. that last piece of code should be just `System.out.println(bytesToHex(md5hex));`

Comment: @Andreas Good catch. I was trying to replicate OP's value(s).